# ASP.Net MVC C# connecting model view and controller together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model, controller

I am trying to get information from the view to the controller function I have. I have looked over many examples and I don't understand how to get information from the view to the controller. I believe the best option would be to bind the model to the view, but I have not found the correct way to do it that works with my code.

Here is my model

```
public class Contact
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller function

```
public ActionResult submit()
{
     Contact con = new Contact();
     return View(con);
}
```

Here is the view

```
@using ContactUs.Models
@model ContactUs.Models.Contact
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<body style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
    @{ 
        var con = (Contact)ViewData["Contact"];
    }
    <div class="text-left">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
            <label style="font-size:38px;"><strong>Contact Us Form</strong></label>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <input name="firstName" value="@con.firstName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <input name="lastName" value="@con.lastName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <input name="email" value="@con.email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
            <label>Message</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <textarea name="message" value="@con.message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <!--<button value="submit" onclick="location.href='Url.Action("submit", "Home")'">Submit</button>-->
            @using (Html.BeginForm("submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label name="warning" value="hello" style="color: red"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to be able to access and see what the user put into the entries when the submit button is clicked.  I tried a couple of things for the submit button and you will see some of it is commented out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am still new to asp.net MVC. Thank you

Comment: Right now you are not posting anything back to the backend since all the `html` fields e.g. `<input name="email"...` are outside of the `form` you are posting back. Put all the fields inside the `@using(Html.BeginForm...) { put the fields here }`

Comment: You do not get "information from the view to the controller "!!!  A controller defines what to do with a response from a server in a client.  The controller puts data into c# classes.  After the controller puts the data into the classes you have to retrieve the data from the classes and put into a view.

Comment: let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a form to submit the data and send it to the controller. Currently, the controller doesn't receive any data. If you want to see what the "submit" function does, you could navigate to `/ConrollerName/submit` where the `ControllerName` is the name of your controller.

You can check this website to see how you could add forms in your project: https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/4-ways-to-create-form-in-asp-net-mvc.php

So essentially you would post the form's data to your controller and view what has been entered.

Here is an example:

#### Model

```cs
public class PersonModel
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets PersonId.
    ///</summary>
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
 
    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets Name.
    ///</summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
 
    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets Gender.
    ///</summary>
    public string Gender { get; set; }
 
    ///<summary>
    /// Gets or sets City.
    ///</summary>
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
 
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person)
    {
        int personId = person.PersonId;
        string name = person.Name;
        string gender = person.Gender;
        string city = person.City;
 
        return View();
    }
}
```

#### View

```html
@model Form_Post_MVC.Models.PersonModel
 
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PersonId: </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonId)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender: </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
                   { new SelectListItem{Text="Male", Value="M"},
                     new SelectListItem{Text="Female", Value="F"}}, "Please select")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>City: </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Here, when you click the submit button, it sends the data to the index with the httpPost attribute on it

Answer (score 0):

You should include all the form fields in the HTML inside the @using `(Html.BeginForm("submit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` block. Currently, all your input fields are outside the form. That is why they are not being passed to the server. When you submit a form, only fields inside that form gets posted to the server.